# Ошибка, после установки Apache NetBeans — не видит Java

Tags: java, ubuntu, netbeans

```
(base) dima@komp:~/Загрузки$ java -version 
openjdk version "11.0.8" 2020-07-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu118.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu118.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Увы, после установки Apache NetBeans сразу :( , "ошибка — нет библиотек Java".

```
cannot access java.lang Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath
```

[image: Снимок экрана]

*[image: Снимок экрана]*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Разобрался :3

Надо сначала нужно узнать какая у вас джава `java -version`

```
(base) dima@komp:~/Загрузки$ java -version 
openjdk version "11.0.8" 2020-07-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu118.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu118.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

потом узнать какую именно джаву вы используете  `update-java-alternatives -l`

```
(base) dima@komp:~/Загрузки$ update-java-alternatives -l
java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64      1111       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64       1081       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
```

потом заходим в директорию `~/netbeans-12.0/netbeans/etc`

```
/home/dima/netbeans-12.0/netbeans/etc
```

В файле `netbeans.conf`находим строку

```
netbeans_jdkhome="/usr"
```

Теперь заходим в папку джавы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я вы браз джаву `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64`

В файле `netbeans.conf`меняем строку на :

```
netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64"
```

Проверяем работу :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]